# Update listbox in c# sql

Tags: c#, sql, ajax

Currently I created a wizard with a listbox. The listbox has a next and previous button. The listbox has thousands of items but the next and previous will show them 30 items at a time.

I am not using AJAX so the page reloads each time the button is being clicked. I don't want the page to reload everytime the user clicks next and previous. I thought of using AJAX.

Is there anyway I can prevent the page from reloading either by AJAX or a different way everytime the user presses next. Pressing next triggers a stored procedure which selects the next 30 items.

C#, SQL, ASP.NET, HTML, JavaScript

Comment: You can use AJAX with ASP.NET 2...

Comment: Well the listitems come from a sql database. The next button will retrieve more items from the same table. This is handled by some c# code calling a stored procedure. I've seem some stuff with ajax and asp.net 2.0 but I need some assistance with c# and ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely use jquery for this purpose. It will allow you to  do an ajax request. In fact, ajax request can be done from a .Net page with even plain javascript and it has nothing to do with .Net version.

However, using jquery will make it easy and you will be able to easily populate the listbox using the results from server.

Comment: the listitems are from a sql database. Does that change anything?

Comment: When you make an ajax request using jquery, it is processed on the server side whereby you can fetch the new values and return it as xml in response to ajax request. The client side script in turn will parse the ajax and re-fill the listbox with new values.

Comment: http://ringdesign.suratdiamond.com/choose_your_diamond.aspx - see this page, the pager does something similar to what you want to do in your app.

Comment: That's very similar to what I want to create

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a small snippet of code? I'm getting familiar with ajax and I'm not sure how I would use it to call a stored procedure in sql and get the result and put it back into a listbox.

Comment: Here is a very good article on how to use jquery - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17203/Using-jQuery-for-AJAX-in-ASP-NET